# Proof of Chernoff's bound: last step missing

Tags: large-deviation-theory

> > Let $\left\{X_i\right\}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables and $S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then, for $\theta\ge 0$, we have
> >     $$
> > P(S_n\ge nx)\le e^{-n\sup_{\theta\ge 0}\left\{\theta x-\log M(\theta)\right\}}, 
> > $$
> >     where $M(\theta):=E(e^{\theta X_1})$.

This is called Chernoff's bound.

---

I started to prove this as follows:

First of all, for $\theta\ge 0$, we have
$$
\left\{S_n\ge nx\right\}\subset\left\{e^{\theta S_n}\ge e^{\theta nx}\right\}.
$$

(For $\theta >0$, we even have equality.)

Hence, for $\theta\ge 0$,
$$
P(S_n\ge nx)\le P(e^{\theta S_n}\ge e^{\theta xn}).
$$
Since $e^{\theta S_n}$ is a non-negative random variable, we can apply Markov's inequality, giving
$$
P(e^{\theta S_n}\ge e^{\theta xn})\le\frac{E(e^{\theta S_n})}{e^{\theta xn}}.
$$
This holds for all $\theta\ge 0$. Hence,
$$
P(S_n\ge nx)\le\inf_{\theta\ge 0}\frac{E(e^{\theta S_n})}{e^{\theta xn}}.
$$
Now, I guess that
$$
\inf_{\theta\ge 0}\frac{E(e^{\theta S_n})}{e^{\theta xn}}=e^{-n\sup_{\theta\ge 0}\left\{\theta x-\log M(\theta)\right\}}.
$$

Unfortunately, I was not able to verify that yet. Can you tell me how to show that this is the infimum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $X_i$'s being independent (i) and identically distributed (ii), you get
$$
\mathbb{E}\big[e^{\theta S_n}\big] = \mathbb{E}\big[e^{\theta \sum_{i=1}^n X_i}\big]
= \mathbb{E}\big[\prod_{i=1}^n e^{\theta X_i}\big]
\operatorname*{=}_{\rm(i)} \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}\big[e^{\theta X_i}\big]
\operatorname*{=}_{\rm(ii)} \mathbb{E}\big[e^{\theta X_1}\big]^n = M(\theta)^n
$$
so you get
$$
\inf_{\theta\geq 0}\frac{\mathbb{E}\big[e^{\theta S_n}\big]}{e^{\theta xn}}
= 
\inf_{\theta\ge 0}\frac{e^{n\ln M(\theta)}}{e^{\theta xn}}
= \inf_{\theta\ge 0} e^{-n(\theta x - \ln M(\theta))}
= e^{-n \sup_{\theta\geq 0} (\theta x - \ln M(\theta))}
$$
where the last step uses the fact that $\exp$ is an increasing function.

**Remark:** this is not the most general statement of [Chernoff bounds](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~rocco/Teaching/S14/Readings/chernoffbounds.pdf) (which hold even for r.v's not identically distributed).